# which is the suitable preposition for the end of " keep/stay in touch"?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any other preposition that we can use after "stay in touch"+with, instead of with?

thank you

Comment: Why do you want an alternative to *with*?

Comment: The choice of preposition can dramatically change the meaning of a phrase. *With* is customary here; *after, through, behind* or whatever would make the phrase say something different. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 2):

We stay in touch "with" people: friends, family, old schoolmates/colleagues, each other, one another

We stay in touch "over" a medium of communication: the telephone, the Internet

We also stay in touch "through" people/places/things: a mutual friend, a disco, a book club (we could also use "via" or "by way of")

We *could* stay in touch "on" or "about" things of mutual concern or interest: a project we're working on (but better here would be "regarding")

We still stay in touch "after" a period of time: years, decades

Sample sentence:
We stay in touch *with* each other *over* Skype and sometimes, when we don't have time, *through* our sister who we both see regularly. We like to stay in touch *about* how the other is doing and still stay in touch *after* forty-four years.

Answer (score 0):

**"with" is the preposition to be used** in this case and I can't think of an alternative that wouldn't change the meaning of your sentence, like "over" for instance.

- "keep you in touch over something"
- "we can keep in touch over the Internet."
- "Why didn't you keep in touch over the years?"

Then again, you can always omit the preposition and just say: **"keep in touch"**.